# Branch cut of the arctan, and integrating in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, line-integrals

I'm doing a Complex Analysis class this semester and I've got this interesting integral problem.

I have to do the following integral:

$$\int_\Gamma \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the circle centered on the origin, with radius 2 (I'm talking complex plane here). I'll be referring to $\frac{1}{1+z^2} $ as $ f(z)$

My basic intuition says that the integrated function is analytic (I can show, not the purpose of this question), so according to Cauchy's Integral Theorem that the integral should be equal to $0$.

Now, the question asks the following: find the branch of $\arctan(z)$ (the antiderivative of $f(z)$), which is analytic on $\Gamma$, to evaluate the integral. I know that the principal branch has two non-analytic regions; starting in $-1$ and $1$ and extending over the axis, but I can't seem to find any branch that will turn out analytic on $\Gamma$. Any thoughts on which branch I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand has poles at $\pm i$, which are inside $\Gamma$.  Find the residues there, and you're done.

But if you don't know the Residue Theorem, compare this integral with the integral around the concentric circle of radius $R$, where $R > 2$.
Since the integrand is analytic on the region between the two circles, those integrals are equal.  Now take the limit as $R \to \infty$, estimating the
integral...

Comment: Residue theory is on for the lecture this friday, but we're not allowed to use it yet. Your method does make sense, but I have to use the $arctan(z)$. 

Thanks anyway, I'll look into this too!

Comment: $\arctan$ has branch points at $\pm i$, and the branch cut can be chosen to be the line segment from $-i$ to $i$.

Comment: Ah now I get it. You can chose them in any direction around those branch points, but as they line op, it's only the segment between the two points? 

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I don't think you do.  The fact that this can be chosen to be the branch cut really depends on the fact that the integral is $0$.  It's not always true that if there are two branch points, you can choose the branch cut in this way.

Comment: For example, $\ln(z^2+1)$ has the same branch points, but there is no branch of this that is analytic on  $\Gamma$.

Comment: That seems rather strange, because the questions specifically asks for it.

The exact phrasing:  
"Consider the integral [...] where $\Gamma$ is a cricle with center 0 and radius 2, traversed counterclockwise. Note that $\arctan(z)$ is an antiderivative of the integrand. 

**a.** Find a branch of $\arctan(z)$ that is analytic on $\Gamma$. (Hint: use the branch defined by $L_{\tau}$ for some $\tau$. Deduce from this that the integral is zero."

Comment: Sorry for the double response, hadn't realized that you were saying that it is possible in this very specific case. I do realize that it's not a property of having two branch points, but rather of the specific problem.